# Is it beneficial to include address in resume?

Tags: resume, job-search, privacy

I have been including my mailing address (which is where I live) in my resume. I got a response from a job I applied for saying that they won't consider me. This was because in their experience people who live in the part of town I do, grow to hate the commute after several months and they're looking for someone long term.

They didn't say which location I would be going to, but I could be willing to relocate. Basically the job was in suburb part of the city I live in now.

Another possible concern is privacy. I'm uploading my resume to several public sites so lots of people could know where I live. I don't really see this as an issue. I live in a shared house.

Is the only benefit of including your address in the resume is in case they need to send you something by mail they won't have to ask you for your address?

Should the address be included in resumes?

Comment: @IshanMahajan OP wrote "mailing address (which is where I live) in my resume". And the question I linked talks about commuting distance and the fact that "most contact is done by phone or email, and not by snail mail". I suggested OP lives where its mailbox stands.

Answer (score 3):

It depends where you live.

French example. If you live in Saint-Maurice, it's an asset. If you live in Bobigny, it's a liability. The demographics of both towns is vastly different, and, unfortunately, prejudice is strong in our country(like probably everywhere else). Prejudiced in favor of Saint-Maurice's demographics, against Bobigny's one.

From what I understand, you live in your local equivalent of Bobigny. That's why J J's answer applies fully.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldnt be mentioning your address in your resume, its not required, its old fasioned, and any type of communication can be done via a phone call or email, if they ever require your house address they can ask for it via phone or e mail.

Address only takes space on your resume and makes you look stupid, people also generalize if you come from a certain locality, having a bad record.

Dont mention your address.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how, specifically, having an address on your resume makes people think you're stupid?

Comment: Stupid is probably not the right word - outdated is probably better

Answer (score 1):

I do not agree with most of the answers here. There are two important reasons, why you should add your address information to your resume.

1. The company would like to see whether you have a valid working permit in the country, in where the company located (or where you will work)
2. If they know your address, they may arrange your interview based on this information. For example, if you are living in the same city, in where the company is located, they can say to you, if you are available tomorrow, we can make the interview.

In your special case, you should not add your full address but the important part of it (country + city)

Comment: I disagree with both points. First, if they're concerned about work permit status, they can ask you during the interview or they can do their research based on your identification presented at the interview (and usually will anyway for the background check). Second, they will call to schedule the interview time and location, and should be asking at that point what would be convenient for you and see what fits for them. Discussions on location of residence should be limited to the interview itself, if discussed at all.

Answer (score 1):

I've always had a public resume and private resume. My public resume includes city and state (in the US) and private resume includes my full address.

The public resume I use on generic job sites, LinkedIn, etc. My private resume is what I submit to actual companies when applying. I've never gone through a recruiter so I'm not sure which one I'd use for that one.

The address itself provides context for the company and it can either be a benefit or work against you, as you've seen.

In your situation where they rejected you automatically does not seem fair, it seems a discussion would have been better suited to give you the chance to at least think about the commute and other options (such as relocation).

The benefit of adding it can be that you show you live locally so relocation is not necessary or you show you live either out of state, country, region, etc. so the company understands that you may need to travel for an interview and plan accordingly.

If you're concerned providing your FULL address works against you, I believe city and state/country is sufficient enough to provide enough information and context of where you are in respect to the company.

Answer (score 0):

The city or town is enough, in todays world email, phone and text is enough to reach out, if they ever need  your address they can text, call and email you for it.Yes for sure you can mention your detailed address in case you are applying for the post of an emergency doctor, or firefighter which requires you to stay in close distance from the place of work.
You can also mention address if you have applied for work from home mode of employment, that would surely require your address.